# Query reults of two other queries to get a third result in ms-access

Tags: ms-access

Recently through all the help here I have been able to get all the queries I wanted to work, but one just doesn't work as well as I hoped in terms of how long it takes to complete.  It can take up to 15 minutes for ms-access to be able to complete and unfreeze.  When I do the query on a small amount of data (150 or so records) it can take 1-2 minutes, but the larger the data set the longer it takes.   
What I am trying to do is take two queries, one that has every result (about 18,000 records), compare it against another that has just all the people that have "passed" and find the ones that have only ever "failed".   This is what a fellow member has shown to me and I used.   
SELECT *
FROM All_ESD_Results_Date_Changed
WHERE ((([EmpID] & [Date]) Not In (SELECT EmpID & Date FROM All_Pass)));  
 Is there a way to speed this up or is it just the limitations of ms-access?  All the other queries I use on this same data set take seconds.
I really appreciate all the help and I never would have been able to get any of this done without the help of this forum.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try left joining the two tables together to achieve the same logic.  Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM All_ESD_Results_Date_Changed t1
LEFT JOIN All_Pass t2
    ON t1.[EmpID] = t2.[EmpID] AND
       t1.[Date]  = t2.[Date]
WHERE t2.[EmpID] IS NULL
```

If this doesn't help, then a further step to take would be adding indices on the `EmpID` and `Date` columns in the `All_Pass` table.

Comment: Both of the items that are being queried are queries themselves.  Will this change the approach or are tables and queries being used interchangeably?   I am still very new to access.

Comment: Your comment makes no sense to me.  As far as I know, my answer is logically equivalent to what you had originally, except that it might perform better.

Comment: I am just confused by your using the word "Tables".  I always thought that tables and queries are different and the relationship between the two is still a challenge for me.  I am still very new working with access and databases in general and did not mean to offend in any way.  I am really great full for the help.

Comment: I'm not offended.  Try my query and let me know if it helps.  We can go from there.

Comment: It works fantastic!   Results in under 15 seconds.  Thank You.

Comment: @Mark Can you mark (no pun intended) this answer correct?

Comment: I think I figured out hot to mark it as correct.  I finally saw that very faint check next to the answer and clicked on it.  It took me some time to see it.